# getting PrivateAccountAPI object from ApiBackend

Tags: go-ethereum

How do I get the `PrivateAccountAPI` object without looping through backend services?

Consider this code:

```
func ListServices() {
    var ethereum *eth.Ethereum
    if err := stack.Service(&ethereum); err != nil {
        return 
    }

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    _=ctx
    apis := ethapi.GetAPIs(ethereum.ApiBackend)
    log.Info("APIs:","apis",apis)
    for  i,a:=range apis {
        log.Info("dump ","i",i,"a.Namespace",a.Namespace,"type",reflect.TypeOf(a.Service))
        log.Info("dump ","api",a) 
    }
}
```

which gives me this output:

```
INFO [11-21|14:51:40|mylib.go:335]               APIs:                                    apis="[{Namespace:eth Version:1.0 Service:0xc42020b6b0 Public:true} {Namespace:eth Version:1.0 Service:0xc42020b6c0 Public:true} {Namespace:eth Version:1.0 Service:0xc42231a1c0 Public:true} {Namespace:txpool Version:1.0 Service:0xc42020b6d0 Public:true} {Namespace:debug Version:1.0 Service:0xc42020b6e0 Public:true} {Namespace:debug Version:1.0 Service:0xc42020b6f0 Public:false} {Namespace:eth Version:1.0 Service:0xc42000e098 Public:true} {Namespace:personal Version:1.0 Service:0xc42231a1e0 Public:false}]"
INFO [11-21|14:51:40|mylib.go:337]               dump                                     i=0 a.Namespace=eth type=*ethapi.PublicEthereumAPI
INFO [11-21|14:51:40|mylib.go:338]               dump                                     api="{Namespace:eth Version:1.0 Service:0xc42020b6b0 Public:true}"
INFO [11-21|14:51:40|mylib.go:337]               dump                                     i=1 a.Namespace=eth type=*ethapi.PublicBlockChainAPI
INFO [11-21|14:51:40|mylib.go:338]               dump                                     api="{Namespace:eth Version:1.0 Service:0xc42020b6c0 Public:true}"
INFO [11-21|14:51:40|mylib.go:337]               dump                                     i=2 a.Namespace=eth type=*ethapi.PublicTransactionPoolAPI
INFO [11-21|14:51:40|mylib.go:338]               dump                                     api="{Namespace:eth Version:1.0 Service:0xc42231a1c0 Public:true}"
INFO [11-21|14:51:40|mylib.go:337]               dump                                     i=3 a.Namespace=txpool type=*ethapi.PublicTxPoolAPI
INFO [11-21|14:51:40|mylib.go:338]               dump                                     api="{Namespace:txpool Version:1.0 Service:0xc42020b6d0 Public:true}"
INFO [11-21|14:51:40|mylib.go:337]               dump                                     i=4 a.Namespace=debug  type=*ethapi.PublicDebugAPI
INFO [11-21|14:51:40|mylib.go:338]               dump                                     api="{Namespace:debug Version:1.0 Service:0xc42020b6e0 Public:true}"
INFO [11-21|14:51:40|mylib.go:337]               dump                                     i=5 a.Namespace=debug  type=*ethapi.PrivateDebugAPI
INFO [11-21|14:51:40|mylib.go:338]               dump                                     api="{Namespace:debug Version:1.0 Service:0xc42020b6f0 Public:false}"
INFO [11-21|14:51:40|mylib.go:337]               dump                                     i=6 a.Namespace=eth    type=*ethapi.PublicAccountAPI
INFO [11-21|14:51:40|mylib.go:338]               dump                                     api="{Namespace:eth Version:1.0 Service:0xc42000e098 Public:true}"
INFO [11-21|14:51:40|mylib.go:337]               dump                                     i=7 a.Namespace=personal type=*ethapi.PrivateAccountAPI
INFO [11-21|14:51:40|mylib.go:338]               dump                                     api="{Namespace:personal Version:1.0 Service:0xc42231a1e0 Public:false}"
```

Now what would be the Go code to access the PrivateAccountAPI or PublicBlockChainAPI object from the `stack` variable without looping through backend services?

I am looking for something like:

```
personal_api=ethereum.ApiBackend['PrivateAccountAPI']
```

how is this done in Go ?

**EDIT:**

Right now I am using this code to get, for example, the public blockchain API:

```
var ethereum *eth.Ethereum
if err := stack.Service(&ethereum); err != nil {
        return 1
}

apis := ethapi.GetAPIs(ethereum.ApiBackend)
var blockchain_api *ethapi.PublicBlockChainAPI
blockchain_api=apis[1].Service.(*ethapi.PublicBlockChainAPI)
```

But this code uses hardcoded indices like [1], and it wouldn't be reliable if the APIs are moved to another position in future versions of `geth`